# Vuex: Wait for websocket response before dispatching action

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, websocket, vuex

So this is the scenario / premises:

- In order to populate a chat queue in real time I need to open a connection to a websocket, send a message and then set the data to a websocket store. This store will basically manage all the websocket state.
- Before populating the chat queue there's two parameters I need: a shiftId coming from one http API request and a connectionId coming from the websocket. Using those two parameters I finally can subscribe to a third http API and start receiving messages to populate the chat queue.

The problem is that due to the async behaviour of the websocket (or that's what I think, please feel to correct me if I'm wrong) I always get an empty "connectionId" when trying to make the put to that "subscription" API. I have tried with async/await and promises but nothing seems to work. I'm pretty new to async/await and websockets with Vuex so pretty sure I'm doing something wrong.

This is the user vuex module where I do all the login/token operations and dispatch a "updateEventsSubscription" action from the shift vuex module. In order for the "updateEventsSubscription" action to work I need to get the response from the "processWebsocket" action (to get the connectionId parameter) and from the "startShift" action (to get the shiftId parameter) coming from the shifts vuex module:

```
import UserService from '@/services/UserService.js'
import TokenService from '@/services/TokenService.js'
import router from '@/router'
export const namespaced = true
export const state = {
    accessToken: '',
    errorMessage: '',
    errorState: false,
    userEmail: localStorage.getItem('userEmail'),
    userPassword: localStorage.getItem('userPassword'),
}
export const mutations = {
    SET_TOKEN(state, accessToken) {
        state.accessToken = accessToken
        TokenService.saveToken(accessToken)
    },
    SET_USER(state, authUserJson) {
        state.userEmail = authUserJson.email
        state.userPassword = authUserJson.password
        localStorage.setItem('userPassword', authUserJson.password)
        localStorage.setItem('userEmail', authUserJson.email)
    },
    SET_ERROR(state, error) {
        state.errorState = true
        state.errorMessage = error.data.error_description
    },
    CLOSE_NOTIFICATION(state, newErrorState) {
        state.errorState = newErrorState
    },
}
export const actions = {
    signIn({ commit, dispatch, rootState }, authUserJson) {
        return UserService.authUser(authUserJson)
            .then((result) => {
                commit('SET_USER', authUserJson)
                commit('SET_TOKEN', result.data.access_token)
                dispatch('token/decodeToken', result.data.access_token, {
                    root: true,
                })
                dispatch(
                    'shifts/updateEventsSubscription',
                    rootState.token.agentId,
                    {
                        root: true,
                    }
                )
                router.push('/support')
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                if (error.response.status === 400) {
                    commit('SET_TOKEN', null)
                    commit('SET_USER', {})
                    commit('SET_ERROR', error.response)
                } else {
                    console.log(error.response)
                }
            })
    },
    signOut({ commit }) {
        commit('SET_TOKEN', null)
        commit('SET_USER', {})
        localStorage.removeItem('userPassword')
        localStorage.removeItem('userEmail')
        TokenService.removeToken()
        router.push('/')
    },
    closeNotification({ commit }, newErrorState) {
        commit('CLOSE_NOTIFICATION', newErrorState)
    },
}
export const getters = {
    getToken: (state) => {
        return state.accessToken
    },
    errorState: (state) => {
        return state.errorState
    },
    errorMessage: (state) => {
        return state.errorMessage
    },
    isAuthenticated: (state) => {
        return state.accessToken
    },
    userEmail: (state) => {
        return state.userEmail
    },
    userPassword: (state) => {
        return state.userPassword
    },
}
```

This is websocket store: I pass the connectionId to the state in order to be able to use it in another vuex action to subscribe for new chats:

```
export const namespaced = true
export const state = {
    connected: false,
    error: null,
    connectionId: '',
    statusCode: '',
    incomingChatInfo: [],
    remoteMessage: [],
    messageType: '',
    ws: null,
}
export const actions = {
    processWebsocket({ commit }) {
        const v = this
        this.ws = new WebSocket('mywebsocket')
        this.ws.onopen = function (event) {
            commit('SET_CONNECTION', event.type)
            v.ws.send('message')
        }
        this.ws.onmessage = function (event) {
            commit('SET_REMOTE_DATA', event)
        }
        this.ws.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log('webSocket: on error: ', event)
        }
        this.ws.onclose = function (event) {
            console.log('webSocket: on close: ', event)
            commit('SET_CONNECTION')
            ws = null
            setTimeout(startWebsocket, 5000)
        }
    },
}
export const mutations = {
    SET_REMOTE_DATA(state, remoteData) {
        const wsData = JSON.parse(remoteData.data)
        if (wsData.connectionId) {
            state.connectionId = wsData.connectionId
            console.log(`Retrieving Connection ID ${state.connectionId}`)
        } else {
            console.log(`We got chats !!`)
            state.messageType = wsData.type
            state.incomingChatInfo = wsData.documents
        }
    },
    SET_CONNECTION(state, message) {
        if (message == 'open') {
            state.connected = true
        } else state.connected = false
    },
    SET_ERROR(state, error) {
        state.error = error
    },
}
```

And finally this is the shift store (where the problem is), as you can see I have a startShift action (everything works fine with it) and then the "updateEventsSubscription" where I'm trying to wait for the response from the "startShift" action and the "processWebsocket" action. Debugging the app I realize that everything works fine with the startShift action but the websocket action sends the response after the "updateEventsSubscription" needs it causing an error when I try to make a put to that API (because it needs the connectionId parameter coming from the state of the websocket).

```
import ShiftService from '@/services/ShiftService.js'
export const namespaced = true
export const state = {
    connectionId: '',
    shiftId: '',
    agentShiftInfo: '{}',
}
export const actions = {
    startShift({ commit }, agentId) {
        return ShiftService.startShift(agentId)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    commit('START_SHIFT', response.data.aggregateId)
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                if (error.response.status === 401) {
                    console.log('Error in Response')
                }
            })
    },
    async updateEventsSubscription({ dispatch, commit, rootState }, agentId) {
        await dispatch('startShift', agentId)
        const shiftId = state.shiftId
        await dispatch('websocket/processWebsocket', null, { root: true })
        let agentShiftInfo = {
            aggregateId: state.shiftId,
            connectionId: rootState.websocket.connectionId,
        }
        console.log(agentShiftInfo)
        return ShiftService.updateEventsSubscription(shiftId, agentShiftInfo)
            .then((response) => {
                commit('UPDATE_EVENTS_SUBSCRIPTION', response.data)
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                if (error.response.status === 401) {
                    console.log('Error in Response')
                }
            })
    },
}
export const mutations = {
    START_SHIFT(state, shiftId) {
        state.shiftId = shiftId
        console.log(`Retrieving Shift ID: ${state.shiftId}`)
    },
    UPDATE_EVENTS_SUBSCRIPTION(state, agentShiftInfo) {
        state.agentShiftInfo = agentShiftInfo
    },
}
```

Comment: Might be offtopic, but I see the password is saved to the localStorage. Maybe that is a security risk? Usually, an accessToken or similar is persisted, not the sensitive password information.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Kunukn, will look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realized that I have to resolve the promise on the this.ws.message instead. By doing that all my data is populated accordingly, there's still sync issues (I can't feed the websocket state at the moment because due to its async behaviour the state is not there yet when other components try to use it via: rootGetters.websocket.incomingChats for example)  but I guess that's part of another question. Here's the final version of the module action:

```
export const actions = {
    processWebsocket({ commit }) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            const v = this
            this.ws = new WebSocket('wss://ws.rubiko.io')
            this.ws.onopen = function (event) {
                commit('SET_CONNECTION', event.type)
                v.ws.send('message')
            }
            this.ws.onmessage = function (event) {
                commit('SET_REMOTE_DATA', event)
                resolve(event)
            }
            this.ws.onerror = function (event) {
                console.log('webSocket: on error: ', event)
            }
            this.ws.onclose = function (event) {
                console.log('webSocket: on close: ', event)
                commit('SET_CONNECTION')
                ws = null
                setTimeout(startWebsocket, 5000)
            }
        })
    },
}
```

Anyways, thanks @Eldar you were in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert your WebSocket action into a promise that resolves when WebSocket is connected.:

```
export const actions = {
    processWebsocket({ commit }) {
      return new Promise(resolve=> {
        const v = this
        this.ws = new WebSocket('mywebsocket')
        this.ws.onopen = function (event) {
            commit('SET_CONNECTION', event.type)
            v.ws.send('message')
              resolve();
        }
        this.ws.onmessage = function (event) {
            commit('SET_REMOTE_DATA', event)
        }
        this.ws.onerror = function (event) {
            console.log('webSocket: on error: ', event)
        }
        this.ws.onclose = function (event) {
            console.log('webSocket: on close: ', event)
            commit('SET_CONNECTION')
            ws = null
            setTimeout(startWebsocket, 5000)
        }
     });
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eldar but I still get an empty connection Id after doing what you suggest. When I check the network tap on the browser, the requested payload for the subscription API is {"connectionId": ""} which means the connectionId is still not there when the API need it. Do I have to make any changes to the "updateEventsSubscription" maybe ?

Comment: @Lowtrux I think `connectionId: rootState.websocket.connectionId` should be => `connectionId: rootState.websocket.ws.connectionId,` As the `websocket` refers to the state and `ws` to the property which is the actual Websocket.

Comment: Not really @Eldar. the websocket in rootState.websocket.connectionId refers to the connectionId property within the vuex module "websocket" and it works properly, everything is namespaced.